# How to load very large CSV dataset into d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

As the title suggests, I have a CSV file (~250mb and 700k rows) which I am not able to load into d3. I tried to load it the way I usually do for csv files but no luck. Currently, it does not error out and I get an empty data array in the console. Not sure if the file is too big or I'm loading it incorrectly. Will appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

```
            var dataset;
            d3.csv("Consumer_Complaints.csv", function (error, data) {
                if (error) {  
                    console.log(error);  
                } else {
                    console.log("file load successful?");
                    console.log(data);   

                    dataset = data;
                }
            });
```

Comment: How are you running this file? Javascript (in the browser) doesn't have access to your local file system.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid IIS via Visual Studio

Comment: Think about DOM.  Look at [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com).  Don't crush your machine's memory or hit the browser's hard-coded limit :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with D3, but with JavaScript in general. D3 imposes no limit on the size of the file it can load and parse.

Javascript runs (with some exceptions) at the *client* side. That means your code has to download (if in a different server) all that **huge** CSV file and, not only that, it has to parse those hundreds of thousands of rows in a huge array of objects. It's simply too much.

So, common sense tells us to think about:

- the user's connection speed
- the user's processing power
- the user's patience to stare at a blank screen for minutes, waiting until the data is downloaded/parsed.

This is a demo that loads a huge CSV file (from the [data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/consumer-complaint-database/resource/2f297213-7198-4be1-af1e-2d2623e7f6e9) site), you can see in the console the amount of data loaded. I also put a `console.time` to show the total time needed to download and parse the file (if you have patience to wait until the end, I hadn't):

```js
console.time("totalTime:");
d3.csv("https://data.consumerfinance.gov/api/views/s6ew-h6mp/rows.csv")
    .on("progress", function(evt) {
        console.log("Amount loaded: " + evt.loaded)
    })
    .get(function(data) {
        console.timeEnd("totalTime:");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this Gerardo, looks like I need to process the data on my end first and create smaller datasets that I can feed to the graphs.

Comment: Yes, that's the best approach.