# d3.text data file size won't load more than 160k lines or 250M

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to load a file using `d3.text` that's around 200k lines long.  I can load files up to 160k lines (249M), but after that `d3.test` just exits immediately instead of trying to load.  Is this a limitation of `d3.text` or is it a limitation on file size or a limitation of the XHR call?

Thanks,
Denise

Comment: 'just exits immediately' - sounds like there's no error thrown? Which may mean out of memory. I've mainly dealt with large files in c# using streaming, not sure how that's done in d3. This SO question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323292/how-to-load-very-large-csv-dataset-into-d3. Papa Parse looks useful.

Comment: Answering only your question, without asking **why** are you doing this: No, there is no limit for `d3.text`. User's patience and computer/network's resources, on the other hand, do have limits! :-)

Comment: @Gerard Furtado Well, up until 160k it just takes more and more time to load.  After 160k/250M it just exits immediately with no attempt at a load.  I'm wondering if there's a built in limit somewhere that's getting triggered?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This can be a browser issue, or a server issue, or something else.